# PHPUnit AbstractPHPProcess Unserialize

Tags: php, unit-testing, serialization, phpunit

I'm working with some legacy code, this is an API call. The code modifies headers and outputs JSON back via a print statement.

In order to have tests for this and not worry about the headers portion, I'm tagging the test with:

```
/**
 * @runInSeparateProcess
 * @preserveGlobalState disabled
 */
```

The test runs up to the point where the code runs a `print` statement with JSON (the JSON is an array that we `json_encode`).

I've looked around the web for a solution to writing tests for output and how to solve the following exception but to no avail:

```
    PHPUnit\Framework\Exception: {"error":"invalid_request","error_description":"Invalid parameter or parameter missing"}

Caused by
ErrorException: unserialize(): Error at offset 0 of 99 bytes in /vagrant/lib/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Util/PHP/AbstractPhpProcess.php:301
Stack trace:
```

How can I write a unit test for this case?

Thank you

Comment: use output buffering to capture it.  `ob_*` functions (`ob_start` and `ob_get_clean`).  Plus you want to use `json_decode` and not `unserialize`  You can also use `header_register_callback`  http://php.net/manual/en/function.header-register-callback.php  To "Magically" unset headers before they are sent.

Comment: Unserialize is called automatically by AbstractPHPProcess unfortunately, so not sure how to handle it still.

Comment: Is that part of vagrant?  I've never used that.  If it is and it's common to use PHPUnit (something I have used) with it, then I would check with their documentation and support.  It wouldn't be a great Idea to make changes to it if it's part of a distributed package.